# Class instance event field always null

Tags: powershell, events

i just study a powershell. and i have a little problem. for example :

```
class a
{
    [eventhandler]$event;
    a()
    {
        $this.event+=[b]::method($this,[c]::new(3)) #inside constuctor i add static method as a handler           
    }
}
class b
{
    static method([object]$s,[eventargs]$ea)
    {
        # do smthng;
    }
}
class c:System.EventArgs
{
    $x;
    c($i)
    {
        $this.x = $i
    }
}
$aInstance = [a]::new(); 
$aInstance.event -eq $null # TRUE
```

Whatever i do, my instance event always NULL. What i do wrong?

Comment: as addition to the above. if i try lambda. then OK 
[eventhandler]$x = { Param($inp1,$inp2) write-host "" } # OK

Comment: finally a solve a half of a problem by putting my method into brackets like a lambda '$this.event+={[b]::method($inp1,$inp2)}' . But now i have a new problem, when i invoke my event with some arguments. this arguments in method body are Empty

Answer (score 0):

so sad. but in ps v.5.1 events works with some errors, i mean self declarated events; Everything ok in ps v7 core